# What is the parameter in onClick callback of Clickable text?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am writing a composable that contains a ClickableText.
I am creating an handler within my composable that would wrap up the onClick callback of the ClickableText
Basically I would create my callback with no argument and inside the onClick of the ClickableText, I would do
onClick = myCallback
This isn't possible because my callBack won't accept any argument and ClickableText's onClick has an argument, an integer and when I mouse over it, it is being said that This callback is called with clicked character's offset.

Concretely, what does that mean?
Could someone explain to me what is that argument, this character's offset?

Comment: Please provide the code example as well for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've written yourself and is noted [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary#ClickableText(androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1)), the `onClick` is:

> Callback that is executed when users click the text. This callback is called with clicked character's offset.

**What does that mean?**

The composable registers whenever as user clicks on its text content and allows the developer to notice those interactions by providing an `onClick` callback.
The offset describes on / between which of the displayed characters the user clicked.
For example, having the text "This is my text" when the user clicks on the 'y', the offset provided as parameter should be 9. That is, because it's the 10th character and you need to move 9 places (offset) starting from the first character to reach that character.

**Why isn't it compatible?**

You haven't posted any code, so I assume your own composable looks along the lines of:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyWrapper(val myClick: () -> Unit) {
    ClickableText(
        text = AnnotatedString("Click Me"),
        onClick = ...
    )
}
```

As can be seen, the type of your callback parameter is `() -> Unit`, a function that receives no parameters and has no return value.

The `onClick` callback of `ClickbleText` is a little different however. It's type is `(Int) -> Unit`, a function that receives a single parameter of type `Int` and has no return value.

Thus you cannot use one function type in the place of the other directly. However, you can implement the `(Int} -> Unit` as [an lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type) which in turn calls your callback function.

Here's an example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyWrapper(val myClick: () -> Unit) {
    ClickableText(
        text = AnnotatedString("Click Me"),
        onClick = { offset -> 
            println("User selected character at offset $offset")
            myClick.invoke() // invoke your callback
        }
    )
}
```

In case your not interested in the `offset` value, you can ignore it.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyWrapper(val myClick: () -> Unit) {
    ClickableText(
        text = AnnotatedString("Click Me"),
        onClick = { _ -> 
            myClick.invoke() // invoke your callback
        }
    )
}
```